# Stupid Java multiple class variable-sharing question.

Tags: java

Summer's clearly been too long.

Alright, I have two separate classes. One contains my main() method and an arraylist of Song objects. The Song object has a method in it that needs to access the arraylist from the original class. The arraylist is public. I created an instance of the first class, called "guide", and tried to call the arrayList as shown:

```
Song temp = guide.songList...;
```

with no luck (couldn't resolve "guide"). I also tried it without "guide." with no success (couldn't resolve songList).

Both classes are in separate files but in the same /src folder (default package). Any ideas? I feel like I'm just overlooking something really stupid that I've forgotten over the summer.

Comment: I think you'll need to post more code

Comment: show us more code, we need to see the context of the line of code you show

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason you are out of scope of the `guide` variable. You should review [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html)  and [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) to refresh your knowledge about variables.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your design is wrong. If the Song object is a part of the list, why does it need access to the whole list? Do you want to search similar songs?

You might want to have a SongManager (or SongCollection or similar) object which holds the list, and then give each Song a reference to its manager.